# Сложные условия в switch

Tags: java, switch

Есть `if`, а есть `switch`. Если использовать `if` то "или" будет записываться как `( условие | условие )`. Можно ли сделать подобное в при помощи `switch`? Моя кривая интуиция:

```
int x = 10
switch (x){
    case 1| case 2:
        ...
}
```

Конечно же, можно не парится, и записать это как:

```
switch (x){
    case 1:
        ...
    case 2:
        ...
}
```

...Но такой способ прошу не рассматривать.

Comment: не знаю, как в `java`, но в `c#` можно записать так
`case 1: case 2: case 3:          
    // Do Something
    break;`

Они синтаксически похожи, по этому попробуйте этот способ

Comment: Нет, java не позволяет так сделать

Comment: @rjhdby только что проверил [ссылка](http://joxi.ru/Dr8na1Yh46jLW2) - позволяет

Comment: @Lolidze вы сами догадаетесь, что ерунду сказали или вам прозрачно намекнуть, что по ссылке тот вариант(второй), который автору не нужен?

Comment: @rjhdby я тоже так подумал сначала, потом внимательнее посмотрел...

Comment: @rjhdby чтож вы так агрессивно ? сами не доглядели, перечитайте вопрос, а поток посмотрите ссылку, что я привел.

Comment: @Lolidze `case 1| case 2:` и `case 1: case 2:` отличаются как минимум тем, что в первом случае не удастся, по ошибке или в качестве временного костыля например, добавить логики между двумя условиями

Comment: @rjhdby к чему этот комментарий ? ТС говорил, что его не устраивает другой способ, а про `case 1| case 2`: , что он хочет примерно так, но такой способ не работает, я предложил немного исправленный способ, ТСа устроил.

Comment: @Lolidze Как вы сами выразились это "немного исправленный способ". Я рад, что ТСа он устроил, но это не равнозначные способы и он не обеспечивает ровно того поведения, которое обеспечивает `case 1| case 2:`

Comment: @rjhdby почему это ? `case 1| case 2` стоит оператор `или`, тобишь или `case 1` или `case 2`, тоже самое в `case 1: case 2:` или `case 1` или `case 2`

Comment: @Lolidze потому, что `case 1 someFunc(); | case 2: someFunc2();` выдаст ошибку (допустим, что конструкция с `|` валидна), а `case 1: someFunc(); case 2: someFunc2();` отработает одну или обе функции в зависимости от значения аргумента

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В примерах кода часто вижу вторую реализацию, скорее всего — это стандарт:

```
switch (x){
    case 1:
    case 2:
        ...
        break;
    case 3:
        ...
        break;
}
```

---

В комментариях подтвердили, что это стандарт. Вот документация с сайта Oracle — [ссылка](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).

Comment: это описано в документации с примерами https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: @rdorn, не знал, что есть документация по switch'ю.

Comment: спецификация есть на все, а вот стандарта, увы, до сих пор нет, ни на java, ни на C#.